# Sapper: CSS smooth scrolling for anchor links has unwanted impact on route links

Tags: css, sapper

In a Sapper application, I'm using CSS smooth scrolling for a better effect when navigating with anchor links within a given page (route):

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth
}
```

However, this causes navigation to other routes to behave in an unwanted manner: instead of being reset to the top of the page, the scroll position remains unchanged from the previous route (in Firefox). (In Chrome, same thing, but the page then smoothly scrolls back to top.)

I understand that this is because of how Sapper works, but is there a known solution allowing to use CSS smooth scroll (for anchor links) while having route navigation work "as expected" and go directly to the top of the page on load?

Live example here: https://www.cinematheque.fr/henri/. `html { scroll-behavior: smooth; }` is commented out, you can activate it in the devtools. The block under the title is a bunch of anchor links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to create a function for anchor links that uses window.scrollTo to scroll to your element, this allows you to disable the html css directive that breaks your app

I wrote this quick example : https://svelte.dev/repl/0a9f812027da4d99b253f39a1941986c?version=3.31.0

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I needed. I will try to improve it so that the hash appears in the URL and an history entry is added (and I'd like history to be navigated with the same scroll effect).